# Como tener un repositorio personalizado no asociado a una entidad en Symfony

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, symfony, doctrine2, symfony4

Tengo un archivo `DefaultRepository` para colocar todas las consultas generales ahi.

¿Sería posible tener un repositorio personalizado no asociado con una entidad en `Symfony`? Me gustaría poner en ella todas las consultas que no encajen bien en otros repositorios (puede referirse a una jerarquía abstracta o de entidad).

Para utilizar el repositorio en el controlador que cambios debo hacer:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepositoty (/ * ??? * /) debe reemplazarse?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pregunta la coloque en la versión de ingles de stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090535/having-a-custom-repository-not-associated-to-an-entity-in-symfony

Luego de varias preguntas pude tener la respuesta que necesitaba, sobre la misma genere un resumen, espero les sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53176838/2400373

Uso symfony 3.3.x . De esta manera solucione el problema

Archivo service.yml:

```
//service.yml
services:
     app.queriesmanager:
          class: AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager
          autowire: true
```

Archivo AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager.php

```
//AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class QueriesManager  {
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3)
    {
        $dql1 = "";
        $dql2 = "";
        $dql = "SELECT pl
                      FROM BackendBundle:Products p
                      JOIN BackendBundle:Pricelist pl
                      WITH p.peachitemid =  pl.peachitemid
                      WHERE p.hasimages =  1
                      AND p.active = 'FALSE'
                      AND p.imagesamazon1 = 1
                      AND p.imagesamazon2 = 1
                      AND (p.descriptionforsales like '%$var%' OR p.itemid like '%$var%')";

        if ($var1 != "select") {
            $dql1 = " AND p.newcategory='$var1' AND p.newsubcategory='$var2' ";
        }
        if ($var3 == "150") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail < 150";
        }
        if ($var3 == "200") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail > 150 AND pl.retail < 250 ";
        }
        if ($var3 == "250") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail > 250 ";
        }

        $dql1 .= $dql2;
        $dql .= $dql1;
        $query=$this->entityManager->createQuery($dql);
        $query = $query->getResult();
        return $query;

    }
}
```

Archivo DefaultController.php

```
//Use the service in controller
$query=$this->get('app.queriesmanager')->searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3);
```

Espero les pueda ayudar.